# In Spring boot, from javascript how to access variable defined in application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I am new to spring boot, suppose I have an variable VAR defined in application.properties:

#### application.properties

```
VAR=foo
```

And I have a freemarker file like this:

#### index.ftl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 console.log("VAR is: " ??? ) // How to access VAR?
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Freemarker Shared Variable:

```
@Configuration
public class FreemarkerConfiguration extends FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.FreeMarkerWebConfiguration {

        @Value("${VAR}")
        private String myProp;

        @Override
        public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
            FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = super.freeMarkerConfigurer();

            Map<String, Object> sharedVariables = new HashMap<>();
            sharedVariables.put("myProp", myProp);
            configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(sharedVariables);

            return configurer;
        }
    }
```

in frontend ->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvariable = "${myProp}";
function myfunction(){
    alert(myProp);
}
</script>
```

---

Or you can make a api call to get the property value from server side as per Paul Vlasin suggested.

Comment: Would this not just work when using the FreeMarker template engine? I.e. Not for ThymeLeaf - which you can achieve access to spring beans from its templates?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe yes  it's just worked for FreeMarker template engine not for thymeleaf, @mainframer tag `freemarker` thats why i provided info. for freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose that variable over an API call, then execute the call from javascript